# Label every n rows of the group in an incremental order in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A",1],["A",2],["A",3],["B",4],["C",5],["C",6],["C",7],["C",8],["C",9],["C",10]],columns=["id","val"])
```

```
id  val
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   4
C   5
C   6
C   7
C   8
C   9
C   10
```

I need to create a new column which labels every **n** rows at group level of **id** column in an incremental order.
In this example n=2. So after every 2 rows of same id increase the count in grp column.

Expected output:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([["A",1,1],["A",2,1],["A",3,2],["B",4,1],["C",5,1],["C",6,1],["C",7,2],["C",8,2],["C",9,3],["C",10,3]],columns=["id","val","grp"])
```

```
id  val grp
A   1   1
A   2   1
A   3   2
B   4   1
C   5   1
C   6   1
C   7   2
C   8   2
C   9   3
C   10  3
```

How to do it in pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with integer division by `n` and add `1` because python/pandas counts from `0`:

```
n = 2
df['grp'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount() // n + 1  
print (df)
  id  val  grp
0  A    1    1
1  A    2    1
2  A    3    2
3  B    4    1
4  C    5    1
5  C    6    1
6  C    7    2
7  C    8    2
8  C    9    3
9  C   10    3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) with a [`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html) by your factor, and adding 1 since you want the count from 1 and python is counting from 0:

```
n = 2
df['grp'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount().floordiv(n).add(1)
```

Output:

```
  id  val  grp
0  A    1    1
1  A    2    1
2  A    3    2
3  B    4    1
4  C    5    1
5  C    6    1
6  C    7    2
7  C    8    2
8  C    9    3
9  C   10    3
```

Intermediates:

```
  id  val  cumcount  floordiv(n)  grp
0  A    1         0            0    1
1  A    2         1            0    1
2  A    3         2            1    2
3  B    4         0            0    1
4  C    5         0            0    1
5  C    6         1            0    1
6  C    7         2            1    2
7  C    8         3            1    2
8  C    9         4            2    3
9  C   10         5            2    3
```